# Convert Numpy to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having `4D Numpy` array with shape `(202, 64, 64, 3)`, so the first dimension would be the index for the image, and the last 3 dimensions are the actual image.

Then i am having '2D Numpy' array with shape '(202,1)' contains the labels for each image

I want to create a pandas data frame of this containing two columns 'Pixel Array' and 'Labels', so that i can perform some operations how to do that ?

```
Train = pd.DataFrame({'Pixel':X, 'Labels':Y})
```

is giving me error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

How to convert numpy to dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on a randomly generated test set of size (50,20,20,3). I'm making two assumptions here:

1) Your data is called datalist

2) the indices aren't actually stored in the matrix (I'm having trouble visualizing a 4D matrix in my head)

```
Y = np.arange(datalist.shape[0],dtype=int)
X = [data for data in datalist]
Train = pd.DataFrame({'Pixel':X, 'Labels':Y})
```